# Evaluating series using operator

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider,

$$ S= \sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty} \frac{ k!}{x^{k}} (-1)^k$$

now this is, $$ S = ( 1 +D+D^2 +D^3...) ( \frac{1}{x})$$

using geometeric series

$$ 1+D+D^2.. = \frac{1}{1-D}$$

So, $$ S= \frac{1}{1-D} \frac{1}{x}$$

$$ S = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

Therefore , for x<1

$$ S= \sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty}(-1)^k \frac{ k!}{x^{k}}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Is this proof correct? Can I find an expression for l.h.s for x>1 ?

Comment: This is a divergent series.  Manipulations with divergent series, assuming the same properties as convergent series, often leads to nonsensical results.

Comment: How do you define $D$?

Comment: $D$ is the derivative operator.

Comment: D is the big D notation of derivative. It was made by oliver heaviside

Comment: @DDD4C4U your idea is good ,,,,but you have recheck about series of differential operators! You have to change some!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation
$$
S= \frac{1}{1-D} \frac{1}{x}
$$
should be interpreted as the **inverse operator**
$$
S = (1-D)^{-1}\frac{1}{x} .
$$
It would mean
$$
(1-D)S = \frac{1}{x} .
$$
Solve the differential equation $S(x) - S'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ to get
$$
S = \operatorname{Ei}_1(x)\;e^x ,
$$
involving an exponential integral function.  This is, indeed, (almost) the [**Borel sum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation#An_alternating_factorial_series) of the divergent series $S$.

Comment: can you give more detail on borel sum/ how you solved that differential equation

Comment: I added a link on Borel summation.