# Solving an infinite order differential equation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

This question was previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145115/solving-an-infinite-order-differential-equation) but was marked as duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748601/evaluating-series-using-operator) question.

I would like to clarify that in my question, I was asking whether converting the infinite differential equation $1+D+D^2 + \cdot \cdot \cdot$ to $\frac{1}{1-D}$ even possible. To quote myself :

> Is this a correct method of solving this problem? please suggest a proper method to solve this.

But the suggested duplicate just uses the reduction to solve an infinite series problem. There is no mention of whether it is possible.

I am asking the question again expecting an answer.

**Is is possible to convert an infinite order differential equation to first order as mentioned? if yes, how to account for the infinite initial conditions**

**How to solve an infinite order differential equation (if the reduction method doesn't work)?**

Comment: The infinite series is equivalent to $\frac{1}{1-D}$ only if the serie is convergent. This is true when $|D|<1$ with $D$ a number, not a symbol of differentiation. What do you mean with Differentiation $<1$ ? This is non-sens.

Comment: @JJacquelin : yes it is. But that was just an attempt I made to solve the problem in hand (my rationale behind using the formula was mentioned in the previous question. It would be nice if you could check that too). If you could suggest a better way to solve I'll be more than happy. Also, if the method is non-sense, the accepted answer to the suggested duplicate should also be :).

Comment: Assume $f=ax$, then you get $ax(1+D+D^2+...)=ax(\frac{1}{1-D})$. Then $(ax+a)(1-D)=1$. Expanding the LHS, you get $ax=1$. This is contradiction, because if it were true, then the derivative of $f$ would be $0$ instead of $a$. If $a$ was equal to $0$, then $ax=1$ would be false. So to answer that part of the question, no the infinite differential equation cannot be rewritten as $\frac{1}{1-D}$

Comment: @Badr B : I think you missed an $ax$ at RHS. The expression is : $(1+D+D^2 +...)ax=\frac{1}{1-D}ax$. So $(ax+a)(1-D) = ax$

Comment: @RishabNavaneet Ah, you're right. I guess it does work for $f=ax$ then.

Answer (score 1):

Here $D$ is the differential operator, and the formula you need is
$$
I + D + D^2 + \dots = (I-D)^{-1} .
$$
The right side is not a reciprocal.  It denotes the inverse of the operator $I-D$.  So it is confusing to write it as
$$
\frac{1}{I-D}
$$
Also note I wrote $I$ for the identity operator, rather than the confusing $1$.

---

Example with $f(x) = ax$.

$$
(I + D + D^2 + \dots)f(x) = f(x) + f'(x) + \dots = ax+a
$$
and to compute $g(x) = (1-D)^{-1}(ax)$ we must solve a differential equation
$$
(I-D)g(x) = ax
\\
g(x) - g'(x) = ax
$$
the solution is
$$
g(x) = ax + a + C e^x
$$
To get the true answer we must take $C=0$ for some reason.  (The problem is that $I-D$ is not actually invertible, so we have to choose the appropriate inverse.)